# MySQL - Change index on myIsam table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where two columns are used in a where condition.

This is a MyIsam table and both columns hold text and use FULLTEXT as index.

The values in both columns are not unique.

The select statement works pretty slow.

Question is: can I simply remove the FULLTEXT index and use another index instead?

The query that is used is just as simple as possbile:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1=X AND col2=y and col3=z
```

Thanks!

Comment: share the table schema for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE  `tableName` DROP INDEX  `indexName` ,
ADD INDEX  `indexName` (  `ColName` )
```

This shuld remove the old "FULLTEXT" index and add a "NOT FULTEXT" index.